# How to put text based on y axis value (in stead of 0,0 to 1,1 co-ordinate system) in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to put a text slightly above a horizontal line, the value of y where is variable, not a constant in a matplotlib figure. My current code is following:

```
fig, host = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,6))
plt.axhline(y = *a variable between 0-100*, color='r')
plt.text(*x-cord*, *y-cord* , '*Desired Text*', verticalalignment='bottom', horizontalalignment='right', transform=host.transAxes, color='red', fontsize=14)
```

However, the position of the text depends on x-coord, y-coord. As my horizontal line is a variable, every time I have to manually adjust the text position, which is not optimal for me to automate the figure creation.

Comment: You could use `transform=host.get_yaxis_transform()` to indicate the y-position via its y-value and the x-position in "axes coordinates" (0 at the very left, 1 at the right).

Comment: You also might want to read the [difference between the pyplot and the object-oriented interface](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/#pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface). It helps readability and maintainability if you wouldn't mix them.